# Best Database for remote sensor data logging

Tags: database, nosql, rdbms, sensors

I need to choose a Database for storing data remotely from a big number (thousands to tens of thousands) of sensors that would generate around one entry per minute each.

The said data needs to be queried in a variety of ways from counting data with certain characteristics for statistics to simple outputting for plotting.

I am looking around for the right tool, I started with MySQL but I feel like it lacks the scalability needed for this project, and this lead me to noSQL databases which I don't know much about.

Which Database, either relational or not would be a good choice?

Thanks.

Comment: An average MySQL-based website has 10K users online constantly, generating data (messages, clicks...) every second. So why would this not cover 10K sensors which generate few bytes every minute?

Comment: Do you want to access the data in real-time / near real-time? Or will it be ok if the data is available for querying some time after it was collected (next day, for example)?

Comment: The data should be accessible in real time if possible, a delay of a minute is tolerable for the project but definitely not one day

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is usually no "best" database since they all involve trade-offs of one kind or another. Your question is also very vague because you don't say anything about your performance needs other than the number of inserts per minute (how much data per insert?) and that you need "scalability".

It also looks like a case of premature optimization because you say you "**feel** like [MySQL] lacks the scalability needed for this project", but it doesn't sound like you've run any tests to confirm whether this is a real problem. It's always better to get real data rather than base an important architectural decision on "feelings".

Here's a suggestion:

1. Write a simple test program that inserts 10,000 rows of sample data per minute
2. Run the program for a decent length of time (a few days or more) to generate a sizable chunk of test data
3. Run your queries to see if they meet your performance needs (which you haven't specified -- how fast do they need to be? how often will they run? how complex are they?)

You're testing at least two things here: whether your database can handle 10,000 inserts per minute and whether your queries will run quickly enough once you have a huge amount of data. With large datasets these will become competing priorities since you need indexes for fast queries, but indexes will start to slow down your inserts over time. At some point you'll need to think about data archival as well (or purging, if historical data isn't needed) both for performance and for practical reasons (finite storage space).

These will be concerns no matter what database you select. From what little you've told us about your retrieval needs ("counting data with certain characteristics" and "simple outputting for plotting") it sounds like any type of database will do. It may be that other concerns are more important, such as ease of development (what languages and tools are you using?), deployment, management, code maintainability, etc.

Since this is sensor data we're talking about, you may also want to look at a round robin database (RRD) such as [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) to see if that approach better serves your needs.

Comment: Another consideration: how will the data get from those 10,000+ devices to your database? Were you planning to have them all connect directly to the server (probably a very bad idea, for a number of reasons) or is there a central collector that does all the inserts? Have you thought about using a message queue (e.g. ActiveMQ, HornetQ, RabbitMQ) to manage the incoming data?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, as an amateur I definitely lacked the right approach to the problem. I'll try to run the tests you suggested and see how they go. To answer your questions about the queries they would be much less frequent than the inserts. Also I've never heard of message queues and thanks for the tip. I'll definitely check them out. Also do you think there's any relevant cons on choosing between a SQL or a noSQL database for this type of project? The ease of scalability advertised by some of them was intriguing me but I never really used any of them.

Comment: Indexes will not slow inserts "over time". Inserting data into tree is O(logN). It can be slow to begin with but it does not get worse with time.

Answer (score 2):

Found this question while googling for "database for sensor data"
One of very helpful search-results (along with this SO question) was this [blog](http://tinkerman.eldiariblau.net/storing-and-publishing-sensor-data/):

Actually I've started a similar project (http://reatha.de) but realized too late, that I'm using not the best technologies available. My approach was similar MySQL + PHP. Finally I realized that this is not scalable and stopped the project.

Additionally, a good starting point is looking at the [list of data-bases in Heroku](https://addons.heroku.com/):
 If they use one, then it should be not the worst one.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

you can try to use Redis noSQL database

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer because it doesn't address any of the original poster's concerns (as vague as they are), nor does it give any justification as to why Redis is the right tool for the job. Anyone can google "nosql" and see that Redis is one of the (many) options.